# how to handle JDO app engine transaction ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

Documentation @ https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions explains how to handle DatastoreTimeoutException, ConcurrentModificationException, or DatastoreFailureException using low level API, but how can i handle them if I'm using JDO, are they directly thrown or wrapped in a JDO exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any exceptions thrown from JDO methods are JDOExceptions (with nested exception where appropriate). You could easily verify that by reading the JDO spec ...

Comment: I've seen some checking for exceptions at the first nested exception and some at the 2 level nesting exception [getCause().getCause()] , this is also confusing, how can i know where exactly to expect these exceptions to be

Comment: The root exception thrown by Google's  datastore code will be wrapped in another kind of exception, but you should not assume at what level that will show up.  So, when checking the exception, loop though the cause list using Exception.getCause() looking for the ConcurrentModificaitonException.  By the way, Google's Appengine docs say that a DatastoreTimeoutException and a DatastoreFailureExcption should also be retried (this is a rare case, but may still happen).